# Is Javascript an "other executable code" for iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, app-store, submission

In Apple's guidelines, I saw:

> 2.7 Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected
>
> 2.8 Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected

What I'm trying to do now is to provide a **TextView** that allows the users to enter Javascript and run in **UIWebView** by

```
stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
```

So I'm not '*downloading*' any code, and Javascript is not something '*other*' but part of the **UIWebView's** features.

In some ways, its just like running a regular UGC WebApp in **UIWebView**.

I'm ready to submit the app but still worry about being rejected after a 10-day-waiting...

Anybody knows exactly whether this is OK??

Comment: Just submit it and tell us how it goes!

Comment: @Yuji Okay, but later...

Comment: So you can be 100% sure, best place to ask is via the iOS dev center. Taking a look around I can't see a contact link for general enquiries (only post-rejection or urgent fixes), so best place is the developer forums.

Comment: @Alex, I've also posted  in the dev forums https://devforums.apple.com/message/513221#513221

Comment: Just do it (its better to ask for forgiveness then permission)

Comment: Guys! Approved! "Read for Sale"!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about TOS for a third party service.  Ask their customer service for more information on their policies.

Comment: No, ignore their customer support and just put it in your app, see if it is detected, and then tell no one. You never know until you try. I realize this angers some people, but this has been successful for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your current iOS Standard Agreement.  It may explicitly allow executing Javascript inside UIWebView, no matter whether the Javascript was downloaded or otherwise.  It also may allow interpreting any source code (Javascript or otherwise) that isn't downloaded (e.g. entered as text, as with the half dozen or so Basic interpreters allowed in the App store since the agreement was revised last year).

Answer (score 2):

Interpreting it this way would disqualify, for example, all apps that use Facebook Connect, which shows a dialog in a web view and there's at least some Javascript in it.

So you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot ;-) But theres still some difference: the dialog in Facebook Connect is generated by a pre-written .js file, but I'm inputting in run-time. However, I found some apps like "Basic!" living in the App Store, so maybe its fine.

Comment: On the other hand, the FB Connect code is actually downloaded from the Interwebs, while yours is built into the app :P