# Writing apps for Apple platforms with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, macos

Does Apple allow iOS and Mac apps to use Javascript? Can someone give me examples of how to use it and the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [phonegap](http://phonegap.com)  as a javascript, html and css wrapper in your ios app if you want to create a native app using html and javascript.

Comment: thanks zen.. now, its clear that js is possible on mac / ios.. :D

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a less techy solution, you could also use AppFurnace ( http://www.appfurnace.com ) to create JavaScript & HTML5 apps, packaged as native apps for iPhone and Android. We use PhoneGap (mentioned above), with an added drag-and-drop interface, enabling you to make your own apps.

Answer (score 3):

There's [NimbleKit](http://www.nimblekit.com/index.php) which allows you to make native apps using HTML and Javascript. Otherwise you can use a `UIWebview` which you can execute Javascript in. Look at the `UIWebView` documentation for more info.

Answer (score 2):

There are tools to code your app in javascript and compile it into native code.

But if you want your app to load javascript code at runtime and run it, then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066642/is-javascript-an-other-executable-code-for-ios) for more details.